# When adding a rule to a Product Backlog Item, Can I prepend the Title with the ID?

Tags: azure-devops

In Organization Settings > Boards > Process. If I add a new rule to a Product Backlog Item.

When: A work item is created...

Then: Set the value of... Title to [.........]

Is it possible for me to prepend the title with the ID of the workitem type? So something like:
`{System.Id} - {System.Title}` or whatever the fields would be to evaluate to them... or can I only use plain text in the field?

[image: New work item rule]

Comment: Why do you want to put the ID into the title, when there is already a separate ID property that is readily available?

Comment: @DanielMann - I agree with your logic. It is a company standard they want to set and other have already decided they want to do it that way

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I tested the rule of the work item, currently there is no option to use the "ID" field.

As a workaround, you could use the pipeline with the PowerShell task to [create a work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) first and then [update this work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) title with the "ID" by using the REST API.

If it does not meet your requirements, you could also use "[Request a feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion)" on the left side of Developer Community to open a new suggestion ticket.